# Python Selenium Scraping error when scrape custom element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am trying to scrape custom element, but i can not. My code worked perfectly for previous versions of Selenium and Chrome, but after update it stop working. I can get full page HTML, but i can not reach custom element i want.Here is e code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://w8shippingge.com/customer-zone/')


driver.find_element(By.NAME,'login').send_keys("password")
```

I get error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51742/devtools/browser/eb5109e6-3d4f-4460-bf38-e94f621d2443
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/for test.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.NAME,'login').send_keys("password")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception: TypeError: JSON.stringify is not a function
    at buildError (<anonymous>:323:18)
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00338893+48451]
        (No symbol) [0x002CB8A1]
        (No symbol) [0x001D5058]
        (No symbol) [0x001D8176]
        (No symbol) [0x001D9631]
        (No symbol) [0x001D96D0]
        (No symbol) [0x002000C0]
        (No symbol) [0x0020069B]
        (No symbol) [0x0022DD92]
        (No symbol) [0x0021A304]
        (No symbol) [0x0022C482]
        (No symbol) [0x0021A0B6]
        (No symbol) [0x001F7E08]
        (No symbol) [0x001F8F2D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00598E3A+2540266]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x005D8959+2801161]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x005D295C+2776588]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x003C2280+612144]
        (No symbol) [0x002D4F6C]
        (No symbol) [0x002D11D8]
        (No symbol) [0x002D12BB]
        (No symbol) [0x002C4857]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76000419+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C3662D+237]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C365FD+189]
```

i tried to add   **time.sleep()** but no result, i get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not specific about using `Chrome`, try using `Firefox`. It should work.

Change this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

To:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

At this stage, am not too sure about the root cause of the issue in `Chrome` though.

Comment: Nope, i am using Chromedriver

Comment: It works with Firefox, Thanks.  But still want to know what is problem with Chrome :(

Comment: I suggest keep this questioned unanswered for some more days, so that others can answer. If you do not get any other answer with the real problem with Chrome, then you can close this question by accepting this answer. Good luck.